# Switch to child windows [ By using while.HasNext() function]

Tags: java, selenium

I want to switch from parent window to child window in selenium without using enhanced for loop, till now the code I used to switch from parent to child is given below,

```
for(String handles : windows1)
{
    w.switchTo().window(handles);
    Thread.sleep(3000);
}
```

But when I execute this code 5 times, 3 times selenium switches to child window, but 2 times it fails to switch. Someone kindly bring up a good solution to switch to child window, and also it should never fail even if I execute N number of times.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing regarding the failure to switch might be because of wait issue. You might have clicked on a link to open a new window but the new window is not registered by Selenium. For loop will never fail to iterate if the `windowHandles` contain the expected number of windows.

```
// Get the current active window (parent window) 
String parentHandle  = driver.getWindowHandle();

// click or do an operation to open a new window
w.findElement(By.id('linkToOpenNewWindow')).click();


// loop max 10 times waiting 5 seconds between each iteration
// until the windowHandles size > 1 
Set<String> windows1 = null;
for (int i=0 ; i<10 ;i++) {
    windows1 = driver.getWindowHandles();
    if (windows1.size() > 1 || windows1 != null) {
        break;
    Thread.sleep(5000);
}

Assert.assertTrue(windows1.size()>1, "There is no child window");

// Remove the parent handle from the list of windowHandles
// This will prevent the unnecessary looping to the active window
windows1.remove(parentHandle);

// iterate through the windowHandles
for(String handles : windows1) {
    w.switchTo().window(handles);
    Thread.sleep(3000);
}
```

Comment: Hi Sighil, Thanks for the solution, I have a small concern here, could you explain this below coding part alone ??  Set<String> windows1 = null;
for (int i=0 ; i<10 ;i++) {
    windows1 = driver.getWindowHandles();
    if (windows1.size() > 1 || windows1 != null) {
        break;
    Thread.sleep(5000);
}

Comment: as i mentioned in the code comments, this loop waits until the number of window handles is greater than 1. If the size is <=1, we wait for 5 seconds and then check again. This is repeated for 10 times.

Comment: I have added an assertion to fail the test case if the windowHandles <=1

Comment: Okay thanks a lot, let me check and get back to u :)